# Why is the y-axis in this R plot showing invalid percentage values?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Why are the percentages in the y-axis of this bar chart displayed incorrectly (values larger than 100%) and how can I fix it?

```
qplot(tctype,tccount,data=categ,xlab="Type",ylab="",geom = "bar")+ scale_y_continuous(formatter="percent")
```

[image]

This is the data frame

```
categ
                  tctype tccount
1  inthread (10 or less)   16228
2 occasional (10 to 100)    3561
3 addicted (100 to 1000)     327
4        communal(1000+)      10
```

Comment: Maybe try qplot(tctype,tccount/sum(tccount),data=categ,xlab="Type",ylab="",geom = "bar")+ scale_y_continuous(formatter="percent")

Comment: It's displaying it correctly, `16228 = 1622800%`, you'll have to normalize the data yourself as suggested.

Comment: I see, I thought the formatter part would do it automatically. This is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mark999 mentioned in the comment above, I needed to normalize the data like this:

```
plot(tctype,tccount/sum(tccount),data=categ,xlab="Type",ylab="",geom = "bar")+ scale_y_continuous(formatter="percent")
```